# Personal One Drive Microsoft Graph binding in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

How do you use the One Drive Microsoft Graph Binding with personal one drive ?

When running an Azure Function created in Azure Portal with One Drive Input Binding, an exception occurs and I receive the following error :

```
Code: BadRequest
Message: Tenant does not have a SPO license.
```

As I don't have Office 365 on this azure tenant, I understand that I could have this kind of error if I was requested a file from One Drive Business but I am using a Microsoft account (UserFromId).

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Microsoft account authentication for the azure function from AAD
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-microsoft
When you configure Input Binding click manage 
[image]

then choose mIcrosoft account

[image]

Goto this link
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/applicationsListBlade

choose manage personal account
[image]

register a new application
and then add the client secret to the application
[image]

and give it update permission or read write to Onedrive
[image]
To get the user ID:
enter your azure function URL as below to authenticate
https://yourfunction.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad

then access
https://yourfunction.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me
grab `user_id`

enter your outlook.com user ID as below:
[image]

Comment: Interesting but I am little bit lost here, I thought that Azure Active Directory worked for both business accounts and Microsoft accounts, so having to configure Microsoft as a provider seems weird, especially with different permissions. 

Microsoft Graph documentation don't mention at all the wl.skydrive_update permission, I have the feeling that it is the old way to do that not the Microsoft Graph way. Am I wrong and it's just not well documented ?

Comment: yes it works for both in preview feature that manages apps in old and new portal. so since you are using onedrive personal you have to configure a microsoft account, the documentation is not clear around that so I had to to do trial and error, please try this ane let me know, more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/app-registration?view=odsp-graph-online

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know.

Comment: Still the same error but might be a configuration issue. 
I am using User From Id and took the id of my microsoft account in the active directory. Is it correct or is it a different id ?

Comment: I updated the answer with user id , it is your personal email. Expand Ducmentation Link in trigger input binding to get more information.

Comment: Thanks. It's better but still causes an error : Failed to refresh ********@live.fr AAD error=Forbidden You do not have permission to view this directory or page. I also tried with user_id which happens to be my name and not my personal email but it didn't work either. Is there something more to configure ?

Comment: change azure function identity to UserFromRequest , then add X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN header with value of id_token, it will work as described in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph#onedrive-input  and https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension/issues/54