# How to create a function that triggers on OneDrive file like I can do on BlobStorage?

Tags: typescript, azure-functions

I need to trigger an `azure function` on a file created in a specific folder in `OneDrive` for Business. The function should output another file in another folder of the `OneDrive`.
I am asking here because the Azure Docs are admittedly in need of update and improvement for Beginners.

Comment: You could [configure and work with Microsoft Graph triggers and bindings in Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-microsoft-graph) to achieve onedrive input and output binding.

Comment: That is the problem. The documentation is very sparse only mentioning you should create a Graph subscription and then refresh and then you can trigger on it. But there is no actual example of how to do that end-to-end and there too many open questions. For example how do I do the authentication?

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621763/personal-one-drive-microsoft-graph-binding-in-azure-functions/54627660#54627660

Comment: Have you reviewed Azure Logic Apps to trigger on One Drive File ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedriveforbusiness

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedrive

Comment: @KetanChawda-MSFT Is Azure Logic Apps the "best practice" way to trigger a function on OneDrive or is it just a workaround?

Comment: @StoyanAtanasov Functions and Logic Apps are Azure services that enable serverless workloads. Azure Functions is a serverless compute service, whereas Azure Logic Apps provides serverless workflows. You can mix and match services when you build an orchestration, calling functions from logic apps and calling logic apps from functions. Choose how to build each orchestration based on the services' capabilities or your personal preference. The following table lists some of the key differences between these services.

Comment: Documentation for comparison: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs#compare-azure-functions-and-azure-logic-apps

Answer (score 4):

Azure function did support OneDrive file Input/Output bindings, but it doesn't support the trigger.

[image]

you could use [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow) to implement it, and there is `When a file is created` [trigger connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/onedriveforbusinessconnector/#when-a-file-is-created) just like  KetanChawda mentioned with [OneDrive for Business connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-onedriveforbusiness).

And it also support [Azure Function connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions), means you could add the function into the workflow if you have to use Function to finish some works.

Comment: That is exactly the question. Azure function **does** support trigger on Onedrive but it is done in an roundabout way - trough Microsoft Graph Subscriptions. The problem is that it is very convoluted and takes a huge amount of time. I have read the docs and am looking at someone that can give end-to-end solution with cloud functions. I have looked at Logic app but it adds another layer of complexity and setup, monitoring and support.

Comment: @Stoyan Atanasov, looks like you could use External file trigger(preview) to do it, but no docs mention it. Here is a same answer to it.https://stackoverflow.com/a/55509155/10383250

Comment: Not yet. I can test it on Monday though.

Comment: I can't figure out how to connect a Logic app to a function app. It is too complicated on a first look. I have to run a ton of experiments and read a bunch of docs. The first tell that this is some workaround is that I Logic apps and function apps are separate entities and not one entity. I don't know what that means for logging, tracking and debugging but I don't feel confident with this solution right now.

Comment: @Stoyan Atanasov, you want to integrate function with logic apps? There are officials doc about how to implement it, you need use the HTTP triggered function and here are docs link. [one link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps) and [two link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-twitter-email).